# How to get user_url part being at site.com/user_url/gallery/slug in case of DetailView?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I want to get link in template from `site.com/user_url/gallery/slug` back to `site.com/user_url/gallery/` using something like:

```
<a href="{% url 'profiles_user:profiles_gallery' -->>>????<<<--- %}" 
class="btn btn-default">"Come back to all galleries and photos"</a>
```

Where instead of `-->>>????<<<---` I need to provide `user_url` argument in order to get such url as `site.com/user_url/gallery`.

```
# site.com/user_url/gallery/slug - gallery details
class ProfileGalleryDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'profiles/gallery_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        print(self.__dict__)
        user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user_url=self.kwargs['user_url'])
        return Gallery.objects.filter(galleryextended__user=user, slug=self.kwargs['slug']).on_site().is_public()
```

`print(self.__dict__)` shows me:

```
{'args': (), 'kwargs': {'slug': 'time-sleep', 'user_url': '1-plus-1'}, 
'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/1-plus-1/gallery/time-sleep/'>, 
'head': <bound method BaseDetailView.get of <profiles.views.ProfileGalleryDetailView object at 0x7fe912b41860>>}
```

How can I get `'user_url': '1-plus-1'` from kwargs in template? Do I need to use `get_context_data` in order to add `user_url` to context?

```
# Core urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<user_url>[\w.-]+)/', include('profiles.urls', namespace='profiles_user')),
]

# profiles.urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profiles_home'),
    url(r'^gallery/$', views.ProfileGalleryArchiveIndexView.as_view(), name='profiles_gallery'),
    url(r'^gallery/(?P<slug>[\-\w]+)/$', views.ProfileGalleryDetailView.as_view(), name='profiles_gallery-details'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class based views, the [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) method includes the view as `view`. Therefore you can access the `user_url` kwarg with `view.kwargs.user_url`.

```
<a href="{% url 'profiles_user:profiles_gallery' view.kwargs.user_url %}">
```